# mysql - conditional insert row within a query with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have a complex query with a ON DUPLICATE KEY Update inside. I only want to insert the last value if there is no row with “timestamp_dag”  = 1420070400, if there is a row with that condition I want to do nothing.

```
INSERT INTO data_prijzen_advertentie (
    `ID_advertentie`,`jaar`,`rijnr`,`status_prijs`,`datum_dag`,`timestamp_dag`,
    `prijs_maand`,`prijs_week`,`prijs_midweek`,`prijs_langweekend`,`prijs_weekend`,
    `prijs_dag`,`prijs_ochtend`,`prijs_middag`
)
VALUES
    (100,2014,1,1,'12-05-2014',1399852800,0,100,0,75,0,0,0,0),
    (100,2014,2,1,'23-05-2014',1400803200,0,75,0,101,0,0,0,0),
    (100,2014,3,1,'30-05-2014',1401408000,0,100,0,75,0,0,0,0),
    (100,2014,4,1,'01-01-2015',1420070400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    status_prijs = VALUES(status_prijs), datum_dag = VALUES(datum_dag),
    timestamp_dag = VALUES(timestamp_dag), prijs_maand = VALUES(prijs_maand),
    prijs_week = VALUES(prijs_week), prijs_midweek = VALUES(prijs_midweek),
    prijs_langweekend = VALUES(prijs_langweekend), prijs_weekend = VALUES(prijs_weekend),
    prijs_dag = VALUES(prijs_dag), prijs_ochtend = VALUES(prijs_ochtend),
    prijs_middag = VALUES(prijs_middag);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's the best if you can handle this before the query string creation..
but if you can't, and your exceptional value is static, you can try something like this:
(I haven't tried to run it yet though)

```
INSERT INTO data_prijzen_advertentie (
    `ID_advertentie`,`jaar`,`rijnr`,`status_prijs`,`datum_dag`,`timestamp_dag`,
    `prijs_maand`,`prijs_week`,`prijs_midweek`,`prijs_langweekend`,`prijs_weekend`,
    `prijs_dag`,`prijs_ochtend`,`prijs_middag`
)
VALUES
    (100,2014,1,1,'12-05-2014',1399852800,0,100,0,75,0,0,0,0),
    (100,2014,2,1,'23-05-2014',1400803200,0,75,0,101,0,0,0,0),
    (100,2014,3,1,'30-05-2014',1401408000,0,100,0,75,0,0,0,0),
    (100,2014,4,1,'01-01-2015',1420070400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    status_prijs = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(status_prijs), status_prijs),
    datum_dag = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(datum_dag), datum_dag),
    timestamp_dag = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(timestamp_dag), timestamp_dag),
    prijs_maand = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(prijs_maand), prijs_maand),
    prijs_week = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(prijs_week), prijs_week),
    prijs_midweek = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(prijs_midweek), prijs_midweek),
    prijs_langweekend = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(prijs_langweekend), prijs_langweekend),
    prijs_weekend = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(prijs_weekend), prijs_weekend),
    prijs_dag = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(prijs_dag), prijs_dag),
    prijs_ochtend = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(prijs_ochtend), prijs_ochtend),
    prijs_middag = IF(timestamp_dag<>1420070400, VALUES(prijs_middag), prijs_middag);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will only have the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` portion run if the timestamp_dag matches the criteria for triggering it. From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an
>   UPDATE of the old row is performed.

So assuming your table is built this way, then the update will trigger.

You can add a `UNIQUE` index using the syntax [as described here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ind_unique_timestamp_dag ON data_prijzen_advertentie (timestamp_dag)
```

Comment: If a add the unique index the update (On duplicate key) of the rest of the rows is also not working anymore....

Comment: So just to confirm, do you actually want the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` part to kick in? From your question it looks as though if there IS a duplicate, then you don't want to `UPDATE` it with the values you're trying to insert at all. You only want to INSERT if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: Alex, i do want to use the update exept for the row with the 1420070400 value.

Comment: What is special about the 1420070400 value? Is that ever going to change? Why is this particular row important that you don't want to update it? (Trying to understand your requirements)